# Live streaming using Flash

Tags: flash, video-streaming, wowza, videochat, flashmedialiveencoder

I was working on an application that streams live video using Flash client and Wowza media server.

As of now, I use an independent desktop based encoder(Flash Media Live Encoder) to publish my live stream.

I wanted to know if it is possible to do the encoding part in the browser? My application would be a used by many to publish their streams so I cannot ask everyone to use FMLE to publish.

I was wondering how do the other web based video chat applications do the encoding part over the web.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Flash Media Server supports accepting a video stream from the browser and pushing it out to other clients live.  I don't know if Wowza has this functionality though.

Comment: what is the web based encoding tool used in that case?

Comment: @James, it's built into Flash Player.  With just Flash you can attach the client's webcam to a netstream and send it up to FMS.

Comment: @James, encoded? of course, you can't send an analog stream over the internet unless it's digitally encoded.  Webcams don't even provide an analog stream, it has to be encoded in some format before being sent over usb.  What are you really asking? Is it H264, no, it's an earlier Flash codec that is supported by both Flash and FMS.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [VideoIO](http://myprojectguide.org/p/flash-videoio/index.html). I'm using it successfully with Wowza Media Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable screen sharing from the browser, you can also use [red5-screenshare](http://code.google.com/p/red5-screenshare/) it works fine with Wowza server also.